# Spring Criteria Api Specification enum list match list values

Tags: spring-data, criteria-api

I have something like this

```
public class Car {

private List<CarCategory> categories;
...
}
```

so every Car can have multiple enum categories, like "FAMILY", "SPORTCAR", "PREMIUM", "AFFORDABLE" etc

I need to be able to get all cars that have all the categories in a specified/given list, for example "all cars that have FAMILY and AFFORDABLE".
All the examples that i have found using "builder.in" assumed that a Car can only have 1 category, but this is not what i want

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the most optimal from the query point of view, but something like this would be functionally correct:

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
cagetories = getCategoriesToFilter();

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Car> cq = cb.createQuery(Car.class);

Root<Car> root = cq.from(Car.class);
for (String category : categories){
    //We create an inner join to filter those cars that do not have a category
    Join<Car,CarCategory> join = root.join("categories",JoinType.INNER);
    join.on(cb.equals(join.get("description"),category));
}

cq.select(root);

//Due to the inner joins, at this point all the cars that have all the categories of 
//"categories" will appear.
List<Car> result = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```